# Why does this animation work smoothly when opening but it snaps when closing?

Tags: html, animation, transition

Here's the relevant HTML

```
    <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
        <a class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button id="isClosed" class="dropbtn" onclick="openDropdown()">Manual</button>
            <button id="isOpen" class="dropbtn" onclick="closeDropdown()" style="display:none">Manual
            </button>
             <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Intro</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Body</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Conclusion</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#">Contact</a> 
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
    /* The sidebar menu */
    .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1; 
        padding-top: 60px; 
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%; 
        width: 0; 
        background-color: #111; 
        overflow-x: hidden; 
        transition: 0.5s; 
    }
    /* The sidebar links */
    .sidebar a {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 3em;
        color: #818181;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    /* Container for Links within dropdown */
    .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: .75em;
        color: #818181;
        overflow-x: hidden; 
        height: 0;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    /* Links within dropdown */
    .dropdown-content .dropdown-item {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 0;
        transition: .5s;
}
```

Everything animates/transitions smoothly when I open the dropdown menu, but when I click it again to close, the dropdown items snap close without any animation. Checking this in Chrome's dev tools, the transition property is still intact at .5 seconds. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

you need to write hidden or visible property instead of display none or block.

Comment: Please, add a code example to illustrate your answer whenever possible.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, the animation still remains the same (smooth when opening, snaps when closing) and no visible differences appear. To my knowledge, the only difference between visibility: hidden and display: none is that visibility will leave a space whereas display: none does not.